# Creating a list of buttons from a div

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind and I am trying to make a list of video links that appear to be buttons.

I attempted to do with buttons but manipulating the text position within the button looks like more problems than it is worth. Example

```
<div class="mb-4">
        <h3 class="text-md uppercase font-extrabold text-gray-200 mb-6 mt-6">
             Project Setup and Structure
        </h3>
        <div class="w-full">
            <div class="w-full p-6 bg-gray-800 rounded-xl mb-4 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:cursor" v-for="c in courseContents">
                <a href="/courses/01-course-overview/">
                    <div class="w-full p-4" v-for="section in c.contents" :key="section.id">
                        <h2 class="font-bold text-3xl text-gray-200 pb-4"> {{ section.sectionTitle }} </h2>

                        <div class="w-full">
                            <div class="w-full p-1" v-for="video in section.videos">
                                <!-- Using utilities: -->
                                <button class="w-full items-center justify-between bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                                    {{ video.title }} {{ video.length }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

output

[image]

So decided to try to make the buttons from `div`'s because of its flexibility.

```
<div class="w-full">
            <div class="w-full p-6 bg-gray-800 rounded-xl mb-4 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:cursor" v-for="c in courseContents">
                <a href="/courses/go-grpc-services-course/01-course-overview/">
                    <div class="w-full p-4" v-for="section in c.contents" :key="section.id">
                        <h2 class="font-bold text-3xl text-gray-200 pb-4"> {{ section.sectionTitle }} </h2>
                        <div>
                            <div class="w-full" v-for="video in section.videos">
                                <div class="flex items-center justify-between pb-2" >
                                    <div class="text-xl text-gray-300 bg-amber-200" >
                                        <span class="text-gray-300">{{ video.title }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-sm text-gray-300 font-bold">
                                        {{ video.length }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

However, the output is not what I expected and I cannot seem to get the divs to separate and appear like individual buttons / links.

[image]

I would like it to look something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have the button in there? You dont need to have a button to make it clickable and behave like one. If you dont want the ahref you can make it a div give it `cursor-pointer` and have an `@click` happen.
Basically you have a flex column which holds the cards and each card has `flex flex-col` again, the title is one column and the text below that is one where the content is set to `justify-between` to make the one spans text appear on the left and the other on the right side.

```
  <div class=" flex flex-col items-center overflow-y-scroll gap-5 p-10">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/" class=" w-96 h-32 bg-black rounded flex justify-center items-center" v-for="content in contents" :key="content.id">
      <div class="flex flex-col w-full p-5">
        <span class="text-white text-2xl">
          {{content.sectionTitle}}
        </span>
        <div class="flex justify-between text-white text-sm">
          <span> {{content.video.free ? 'Free Resource' : 'Paid Resource'}}</span>
          <span> {{content.video.length}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jk83naq5/64/#run

Comment: thank you so much for posting and the advice. This is on the right track. A section has a title and in this section there are multiple videos. Where each video is a button with text.